# Scrolling child views in gallery

Tags: android, scroll, gallery, onfling

I need help with enable scrolling the child views (That are not image View) in my gallery.
I understand overriding on Fling() is the solution, but I don’t know how to implement it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the right way to do it. AdapterViews like ListView or GridView used to recycle their child views. So if you try to manually update child views, you're gonna have some troubles.

First, I recommend you to use the **viewholder pattern**. Then, in order to select an item, mark it on your data object and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Gallery which (unfortunately) doesn’t recycle it's views. I am using the viewholder pattern. My solution was to implement SimpleGestureListener. Thank you!